# namespace authorization with oauth2

Tags: kubernetes, oauth-2.0, istio

I have the following the scenario:

[image]

The user1 is going to have access to the services only in the `namespace1` but not in the `namespace2`.
I am going to use **OAuth2** as identity server. 
The question is, how to configure the ingress controller, that only `user1` is authorized to access services in `namespace1`.

When the `user2` is trying to access services in the `namespace1`, then it will reject the request.

Any other solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it at Ingress Controller level. You would do it through RBAC rules.

Something like this:

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  namespace: namespace1
  name: deployment-manager
rules:
- apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
  resources: ["deployments", "replicasets", "pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
```

---

```
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: deployment-manager-binding
  namespace: namespace1
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: user1
  apiGroup: ""
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: deployment-manager
  apiGroup: ""
```

At Ingress Controller level (and depending on Ingress Controller), you could reject requests based on the host, the path; the user is trying to reach, headers and other attributes, but not based on the identity of the user.

Note that the Ingress Controller itself is going to be running in a namespace, so your user needs to first reach it (after being authenticated and authorized), and then be rejected, which doesn't really sound right.

Comment: What is your suggestion? How would you do?

Comment: I would use RBAC rules, like in the answer. Once you have the user, create a Role in the namespace you want (with access to the resources you want). Then bind that role to the user, and you are good to go. That user would only have access to the resources you specified, within the namespace you specified.

Comment: I think, I've expressed me wrong. What I would like to achieve is, that `user1` has access to the services
in the `namespace1` and not to resources. The `RBAC` rules manage resources and not services.
I suspect, I have to solve it on applicaton level, like an authorization middleware in a webservice.

Comment: What do you mean with `services`? A service is a resource/object in k8s. So, just like you could state in the Role object "deployments" or "replicasets", you can state "services", and you would have access to the services (as an object).

Comment: The `user1` makes a request via http rest to the `service1` in the `namespace1`. How do kubernetes figure
out, that the request came from `user1` not `user2`. It does not go through Kubernetes API.

Comment: well, if you make the service public, you need to make the authorization at application level. If this is your case, that the users 1 and 2 are going to make the requests from outside cluster, with k8s native objects you can't do that. I see now that one of the tags of your question is Istio. With Istio you can do that; by setting up headers match in a `VirtualService`, and make your requests with a header like `user: user1`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do it in the application itself using [audience claim](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#section-4.1.3) from the JWT token provided by the oauth provider.

If you don't want to do it in the application and okay with bringing in the complexity of a service mesh then you could use a service mesh such as istio to do it. Here is the doc for [istio](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authorization/rbac-groups/).